# Svg icon does not look the same using react-native-svg compared to standard html

Tags: reactjs, react-native, svg, react-native-svg, figma

I exported in svg format an icon designed in Figma and copied it into my react-native project as seen here, the only change I have done to adapt it to react-native-svg is to use high-caps on `Line` and `Svg`.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Svg, Line } from 'react-native-svg';  
    
    export default {
        
        PauseSymbol: {
            svg:
                <Svg width="14" height="24" viewBox="0 0 14 24" fill="none">
                    <Line x1="2" y1="0" x2="2" y2="24" stroke="#A0978E" stroke-width="4" />
                    <Line x1="12" y1="0" x2="12" y2="24" stroke="#A0978E" stroke-width="4" />
                </Svg>  
   }
}
```

The issue is that changing the value of stroke-width does not do anything. The lines appear very thin when they should have a width of 4.

I tried running the svg in html and it looks fine but not on my iOS simulator using react-native-svg. See html here and expected output: http://tpcg.io/_YSCW1A

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: try using strokeWidth insteadof stroke-width

Answer (score 0):

As @enxaneta said, I had to use `strokeWidth` instead of `stroke-width`. See *Common props* section on [this page](https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg/blob/main/USAGE.md)